# Edited: Retrieve Table entries by adding ID attribute to file name?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database of venues - and I would like to display this data in one page that would only change in some sort of an attribute to the id: (Ex: venues.php?id=1, which would get all the data from row #1.)

**Edit:** Okay, I updated the code and this is what it looks like now:

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()); 

$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = ".(int)$id) ;

 or die(mysql_error());
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['VENUE_NAME'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Address:</th> <td>".$info['ADDRESS'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

And upon going to venues.php?id=1 I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in
>   /home/nightl7/public_html/demos/venues/venues.php on line 8

Comment: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = ".$id) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = ".(int)$id) ;
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error on line 8, I updated my original question with the code and what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In order to "pass" the id into your url "venues.php?id=1"
You need to use a hybrid html/php form with method=get.

You can see an example html form here: [w3schools html forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

This is what I would do:

```
print '<form name="input" action="venues.php" method="get">';
print 'Venue: <select name = "id">';
$con = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db($dataBase);
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
else {
$opt = array();
$optVal = array();
$i = 0;
$sql = "Select * from venues";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $opt[$i] = $row['VenueName'];
    $optVal[$i] = $row['VenueID'];
    print "<option value='$optVal[$i]'>$opt[$i]</option>";
    $i++;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
print '</select><br />';
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
print '</form>'
```

This will give you a form that will give you a drop down list of all your venues and once a venue is selected will direct you to the venues.php page with the respective id.

at the top of your venues,php page just use

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

This assigns the id number to the variable $id and then you can use this "select"

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = ".$id) ;
```

To collect your venue name from your database using the id supplied in the form.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Beyerz, I will read up on it and see what I come up with - but is it possible to get the id from the url? The reason is that I built up a table that opens a modal with this information onClick.

Comment: So did you use a form to pass the ID and then collect the ID on the venues.php page?

Comment: No, I used what I have now with some modifications. A form is good, however not for what I wanted to use in this case. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()); 

$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = ".$id) or die(mysql_error());
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['VENUE_NAME'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Address:</th> <td>".$info['ADDRESS'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```